# Как запустить скрипт Node.js из PHP?

Tags: php, node.js

Мне нужно запустить скрипт `script.js` на **Node.js** кодом **PHP** и записать значение переменной **JS** `ok` в переменную `$var` на **PHP**.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Для единичных запусков - через `exec`, как ответили. Для постоянной эксплуатации - лучше поднять веб-сервер на ноде (это делается буквально за 10 минут), с ним говорить по HTTP. Так PHP скрипт отработает быстрее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PHP**:

```
exec('node script.js');
$file = fopen('ok.txt', 'r+');
$var = fgets($file);
fclose($file);
unlink('ok.txt');
```

**NODE.JS**:

```
var ok = ...;
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile('ok.txt', ok, function(){console.log('Error!');});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$js_path = '/var/www/html/js/';
$js_func = 'nodefunc.js';

$result = exec("cd ". dirname($js_path). " && node ".$js_func." 2>&1", $out, $err);
```